# Use of asterisk in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Why is the use of asterisk perfectly valid in oracle sql when the asterisk is by itself in the SELECT clause, but it results in an error when there are other expressions in the SELECT?

For example:

```
select * from table1  -- is ok
```

But:

```
select field, * from table -- is not ok
```

Comment: For the last few years, I've been searching for a better way of expressing column and expressions in SQL, but there's not much beyond `*`. This is important for an ORM in order to produce valid queries over time, when the tables suffer modifications. +1 to the question, even though I know there's no better answers yet.

Answer (score 6):

Oracle only allows a "bare" asterisk when there are no other columns.

Otherwise, you need to qualify it:

```
select t.field, t.*
from table1 t;
```

I suspect the reason is that Oracle considers `select *` to be a full clause, rather than `*` being an abbreviation for all columns.